# MVC3 in IIS 7.0 Keep getting HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7

I have implemented a MVC3 web application that works in Visual Studio.

http://localhost:1234/Home/Index
This is the home page that works.

I have deployed in IIS 7.0 and keep seeing

**HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.**

Can someone please guide me what needs to be done?  I have copied MVC3 dlls along with the application too.

Comment: Do you have asp.net mvc installed on production machine?

Comment: Have you tried in your IIS manager to pick the website and click a button that says Browse or Go to. When you deploy in IIS you won't necessarily get the same URL.

Comment: In IIS, is your web app deployed as a website or as an application under a website? If it is an application then your URL should look something like `http://server_host_name/application_name/Home/Index` The `application_name` being the name of the application in IIS.

Comment: The ApplicationPool must be set as a ASP.NET MVC can you ensure that it's so?

Comment: @IngóVals - IIS Application Pools have no concept of ASP.NET MVC. They only know about the version of the framework MVC is running on.

Comment: @M.Babcock Yeah, could not remember the exact setting, sorry. Just wanted to make sure he set it to the right framework. IIS 6.0 didn't come with MVC framework if I remember correctly.

Comment: The application pool pipeline must be set to "Integrated" and not "Classic".  Also make sure your web.config file is in the right spot.

Comment: @IngóVals - IIS7 doesn't come with MVC framework either. In fact IIS in general could care less about the MVC framework.

Comment: @M.Babcock So if the IIS isn't on the same computer he installed MVC that could be his problem.

Comment: @IngóVals - Probably not. A 404 error typically means your IIS configuration is screwed up or you're hitting the wrong URL. If it was getting to the point that MVC would even matter, he'd have other problems.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker - Are you sure that your website's `Physical Path` property is actually pointing to the directory you're expecting it to run from? Also make sure that it is pointing to your site's root directory and **not** the bin directory.

Comment: i am running under Integrated mode. It is pointing to root directory but when I go to http://localhost:1234/ it just shows me items inside the physical folder structure. if i go to http://localhost:1234/home/index, i see http 404 error. please guide

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker - You should not be hitting `home/index` directly what happens when you hit http://localhost:1234/home?

Answer (score 0):

Have you made the folder you put the files in to an application?

Comment: its a website. i dont have the menu option to make it a web application

Comment: do you have an option to convert that into web application?